# Debugging JavaScript Timing Events

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm having a problem with this JavaScript script. I've tried a number of things to get it to work. The alerts in there at current are there for debugging purposes, and seem to be failing to occur.

Help please?

```
function checkTime(this_time){
var the_string = "checkTime("+this_time+")";
var now = ((new Date()).getTime());
if(parseInt(now) >= parseInt(this_time)){
    document.write("TIMEUP!");
}
alert(now);
alert(this_time);
var t = setTimeout(the_string,300);
}

var the_time = (((new Date()).getTime())+19000);
var the_string = "checkTime("+the_time+")";
var t = setTimeout(the_string,300);
```

Thanks,

Will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for a countdown?
See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/kACQM/). The code is simplified to:

```
var bench  = 19000 + new Date().getTime(),
    timer  = setInterval(
               function(){ 
                 checkTime(bench); 
               }
               , 1000
             );

function checkTime(this_time){
    var check = new Date - this_time;
    if(check>=0){
        alert('time\'s up!');
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

Comment: See my fiddle for one without an external var :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimeout` with closures instead of strings.

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function(){
  //your Javascript code here
  //"now" can be used here as a closure
}, 300);
```

Comment: @Mic Thanks for the response. I tried changing the script to that, but it's still not working. Not a single alert box. :/

Comment: That's a good first step ;) When you play with timed events, `alert` stops the flow, you should use `console.log(...)` But unfortunately I don't understand what you are trying to do with this code.

Comment: If you want to react after 19sec, why don't you put 19000 at the timeout? If you want to check every 300ms until it reaches 19sec you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: @Mic Ah, thanks, but what I don't understand is that the function isn't even executed **once**, according to my alert();'s.

Comment: @Mic Ah, I've found out what the issue was, it was with a bit of the script that I didn't post. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a safer and self-contained version. A document.write after load will clear the page completely

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Zt5k7/

```
window.onload=function() {
  var timer = function (endTime) {
    var end = new Date(endTime);
    var tId;
    this.checkTime=function(){
      var now = new Date();
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=now.toLocaleString();
      if (now.getTime()>=end.getTime()) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="TIME's UP!";
        clearInterval(tId);
      }
    }
    tId = setInterval(this.checkTime,300);
  }(new Date().getTime()+5000);
}
```

or for a proper countdown http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Zt5k7/1/

```
window.onload=function() {
  var timer = function (endTime) {
    var end = new Date(endTime);
    var tId;
    this.checkTime=function(){
      var now = new Date();
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=now.toLocaleString();
      var diff = end.getTime()-now.getTime()
      if (diff >= 1) document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=parseInt(diff/1000)+1;
      else {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="TIME's UP!";
        clearInterval(tId);
      }
    }
    tId = setInterval(this.checkTime,300);
  }(new Date().getTime()+9000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the code could be made more simple to work.

```
function checkTime(this_time){
    var now = ((new Date()).getTime());
    if((now - this_time) >= 0){
        document.write("TIMEUP!");
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

var t_t = (((new Date()).getTime())+19000);

var timer = window.setInterval(function(){ 
    checkTime(t_t); }
, 300);
```

Cheers!

Comment: @Akshit Soota Thanks very much, but I inserted alert();'s in to test presence of this_time and now but not a single alert was made, neither was the string written. :/

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){document.write("TIMEUP!");}, 19000)` makes the same, isn'it? :)

Comment: But I thought the trouble is that the browser sometimes counts 19 seconds as 23 actual seconds, because the JavaScript slows down?

Comment: @Akshit Soota Ah, I've found out what the issue was, it was with a bit of the script that I didn't post. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Will Manson Glad helping you! :D